# Database normalization made easy?

Tags: database

Is there any easy resource available online or a book which would allow a complete newbie how the database normalization process works and what one should do to perform the transformations on a given database leading it from 1NF to 5NF through all the in-between?

From my research, it seems that the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) seems to be the closest to what I'm looking for but is there anything even easier?

Comment: Please see [Are questions asking for tutorials allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/are-questions-asking-for-tutorials-allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highly depends upon your taste. But I have found that the course in class2go offered by Stanford is quite good. It has a fairly good explanation of normalization up until NF4. For a complete newbie I think this would be quite useful.

You have to sign up but the material is supposed to be there:

http://class2go.stanford.edu/db/Winter2013

Also have you seen this?

http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm

Comment: Thanks for both, will surely take a look! :)